# Python Gradient Vector calculation based on formula

Tags: python, vector

I think I am on the right track but need confirmation of someone wiser than me if my understanding is correct. I want to calculate gradient vector based on formula:

f(x,y) = i*x^2 + j*y

I would like to know if the following code will do the trick or if there is a better way of doing it:

```
def grad_vector(i, j, x, y)

    u = 2*i*x
    v = j*y
    return [u, v]
```

Comment: maybe `u = i*x**2` instead of `u = 2*i*y`?

Comment: Sorry I meant `u = 2*i*x` and `v = j*y` with reasoning being that u and v are partial derivatives

Comment: thanks for clarification. Then probably `v = j` instead of `v = j*y`?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing obvious error indeed it should be `v = j`

Comment: Then the code seems reasonable and "does the trick". "If there is a better way of doing it" depends on many factors, especially where/how it will be used